# Azure DNS: How to configure an ALIAS record to point to some external domain?

Tags: azure, dns, alias

I have a DNS Zone for some subdomain called `"myapp.mydomain.com"` which is managed by the "Azure DNS" product.

Now I would like to point the apex/root of this subdomain to some other domain: `"myapp.mydomain.com"`->`"otherapp.otherdomain.com"`. I could add some A-record with the IP, but this changes from a while. Adding a CNAME-record is not possible on the subdomain apex/root.

I have found this solution here: https://blog.baeke.info/2019/09/03/back-to-basics-dns-alias-records/

But unfortunately I could no figure it out configuring it in the Azure DNS view.

Does Azure DNS actually supports this case or not? If yes, how could I configure it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's impossible to configure alias record to point to some external domains with Azure DNS zone because currently Azure DNS alias records only have the following capabilities:

- Point to a public IP resource from a DNS A/AAAA record set.
- Point to a Traffic Manager profile from a DNS A/AAAA/CNAME record set.
- Point to an Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN) endpoint.
- Point to another DNS record set within the same zone.

If you want to point the apex/root of this subdomain to some other domain, you need to create CNAME records, but we can not added it on the apex/root of domain. Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-cli#create-a-cname-record).

> The DNS standards do not permit CNAME records at the apex of a zone
> (--Name "@"), nor do they permit record sets containing more than one
> record.
>
> For more information, see [CNAME records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#cname-records).

Otherwise, if you just want to point one subdomain to some other domain: `"myapp.mydomain.com"->"otherapp.otherdomain.com"`. I think you only need to create a CNAME type record named `myapp` under the zone `mydomain.com` with value `otherapp.otherdomain.com`.